# Finding the prime element of a place of a function field of a elliptic curve.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $p$  be an elliptic curve in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y] $. Consider the quotient ring $A = \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(p) $ and its field of fractions $F = frac(A) $. For all $f + (p) \in A$, define $deg_A(f + (p))= min\lbrace deg(g) \mid g \in f + (p) \rbrace $.

I want to consider the valuation ring $$\mathcal{O}_{\infty} = \lbrace \frac{f + (p)}{g + (p)} \in F \mid deg_A(f + (p)) \leq deg_A(g + (p)) \rbrace $$ of the algebraic function field in one variable $F/\mathbb{C}$.

The group of units of $\mathcal{O}_{\infty} $ is the set of all rational functions where the degree of the denominator equals the degree of the numerator. Hence the place of $\mathcal{O}_{\infty}$ is the ideal $$P_{\infty} = \lbrace \frac{f + (p)}{g + (p)} \in F \mid deg_A(f + (p)) < deg_A(g + (p)) \rbrace$$

If you accept the fact that every place of a algebraic function field in one variable is principal, then it should be pretty straight forward to find the prime element (generator) of this ideal - but in this case, I'm having trouble finding it explicitly.

In the rational case (when $F = \mathbb{C}(X) $). The prime element of the place $$ P_{\infty} = \lbrace \frac{f}{g} \mid f,g \in \mathbb{C} [X] ,g \neq 0, deg(f) < deg(g)  \rbrace $$ is $\frac{1}{X}$ - but if we let $p = Y^2 + X^3 - X$, then both $\frac{1}{X} $ and $\frac{1}{Y}$ do not work here. Any suggestions on a way to do this?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot rely on the degree as the (negative of) valuation in this case. A reason already shows in the equation
$$Y^2=-(X^3-X)$$ telling that the "degree" of $Y^2$ has to be equal to the degree of $X^3-X$. What works here is, in a way, to declare that $\deg Y=3$ and $\deg X=2$. Try to prove that $P_\infty$ is generated by $X/Y$ as an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_\infty$.

Comment: I have found it to be easier (for myself) to move to an affine part of the projective plane that actually contains the point at infinity. Here the homogenization of $y^2+x^3-x=0$ would be $Y^2Z+X^3-XZ^2=0$. The point at infinity has homogeneous coordinates $[X:Y:Z]=[0:1:0]$, so let's use $u=X/Y$, $v=Z/Y$. Dividing by $Y^3$ shows that in this affine part the curve has equation $g(u,v):=v+u^3-uv^2=0$, and at $P_\infty$ we have $v=u=0$. You see that $\partial g/\partial v$ does not vanish at $P_\infty$, so $u$ gives a prime element. In the original coordinates $u=X/Y$.

Comment: Or in other words, is the element 
$$\frac YX=\frac{Y^2}{XY}=-\frac{X^3-X}{XY}=-\frac{X^2-1}Y$$ in $\mathcal{O}_\infty$ or not? It shouldn't be.

Comment: Or in yet other words. Your definition of *degree* does not satisfy the rule $\deg fg=\deg f+\deg g$. If your definition means that $\deg X=1$, $\deg (X^2-1)=2$, then also 
$$\deg X(X^2-1)=\deg (X^3-X)=\deg(-Y^2)=2\neq \deg X+\deg (X^2-1).$$

Comment: And WELCOME TO MATH.SE!! +1 for showing your work and thinking. If only all the new askers did as well as you did it in describing their thinking in a way that allows us to figure out the source of confusion. Hopefully somebody who actually knows this stuff inside out shows up and writes an actual answer.

Comment: Hey @JyrkiLahtonen, thanks for all the awesome comments. Yes, you're absolutely correct! I

Comment: don't know a ton about projective varieties but I'm interested in what you mean by the statement "declare $degY = 3 $ and $degX = 2$". Do you mean $deg(f + (p)) = 3 $ if $f + (p) \equiv Y + (p) $, $deg(f + (p)) = 2$ if $f \equiv X + (p)$ and  $deg(f + (p)) = min \lbrace deg(g) \mid g \in f + (p) \rbrace $ otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: No, I mean that we use the fact that $A$ is a free $\Bbb{C}[X]$-module with basis $\{1_A,Y+(p)\}$, and declare that
$$
\deg_A(a(X)+Yb(X))=\max\{2\deg a(X),3+\deg b(X)\}
$$
for all $a(X),b(X)\in\Bbb{C}[X]$. I abuse the notation slightly and denote $Y+(p)$ by $Y$ as well. It is not immediately clear why this works. If I think of a good way, I will write it as an answer. One of the routes is to observe that results in a ring that is the integral closure of the valuation ring at infinity of the rational function field in $F$.

Comment: (cont'd) I already started writing an answer based on that, but it became more messy than I had hoped.

Comment: Basically that definition comes from the recipe
$$\deg_A(X^iY^j)=2i+3j.$$ For monomials you get the degree from those of $Y$ and $X$, which is why I initially described this as coming from declaring $\deg(X)=2$, $\deg(Y)=3$. Sorry about not making this clear. The catch is to ascertain that this gives a well defined function on the quotient ring $A$.

Comment: Argh. It should have been $\max{2\deg a,3+2\deg b\}$. That gives the monomial $X^iY$ the degree $3+2i$ in accordance with the second formula.